# Fatal error during command execution (MySQL, VBNET)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, fatal-error

I have a form that have multiple fields. And this form can Add,Edit,Save and Update records. But the Update button gives me error of "Fatal error during command execution" which is I dont know how to find the error in my codes. Here is my codes.

```
 Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=root;   database=dbase"

    Try

        conn.Open()
        Sql = "UPDATE dbase.tblfacultyinfo SET firstname = @firstname, " & _
                                        "middlename = @middlename," & _
                                        "lastname = @lastname," & _
                                        "gender = @gender," & _
                                        "birthdate = @birthdate," & _
                                        "age = @age," & _
                                        "emailAdd = @emailAdd," & _
                                        "contact_mobileno = @contact_mobileno," & _
                                        "contact_telno = @contact_telno," & _
                                        "homeadd_houseno = @homeadd_houseno," & _
                                        "homeadd_street = @homeadd_street," & _
                                        "homeadd_brgy = @homeadd_brgy," & _
                                        "homeadd_town = @homeadd_town," & _
                                        "tersiary_schoolname = @tersiary_schoolname," & _
                                        "tersiary_address = @tersiary_address," & _
                                        "tersiary_degree = @tersiary_degree," & _
                                        "tersiary_batch = @tersiary_batch," & _
                                        "secondary_schoolname = @secondary_schoolname," & _
                                        "secondary_address = @secondary_address," & _
                                        "secondary_batch = @secondary_batch" & _
                                        "WHERE facultyNo = @facultyNo"
        With cmd
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = Sql
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@facultyNo", txtFacultyNo.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txtFirstname.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", txtMiddlename.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtLastname.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", cbGender.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", dtpBirthdate.Value)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", txtAge.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAdd", txtEmailAdd.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_mobileno", txtContact_Mobile.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_telno", txtContact_Tel.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@homeadd_houseno", txtHomeAdd_HouseNo.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@homeadd_street", txtHomeAdd_Street.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@homeadd_brgy", txtHomeAdd_Brgy.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@homeadd_town", txtHomeAdd_Town.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@tersiary_schoolname", txtTersiary_Schoolname.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@tersiary_address", txtTersiary_Add.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@tersiary_degree", txtTersiary_Degree.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@tersiary_batch", cbBatchTer.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondary_schoolname", txtSecondary_Schoolname.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondary_address", txtSecondary_Add.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondary_batch", cbBatchSec.Text)
        End With
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        MsgBox("Data Updated", vbInformation, "Successfully Update Record")
        conn.Close()


    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
        buttons("ResetButtons")
        DataGridView1.Enabled = True
    End Try
End Sub
```

any help is appreciated. Thx in advance.

Comment: first remove all that vars and only update one, first name. and see if it works.

Comment: You use AddWithValue. This means that the DataType of the parameter passed is decided looking at the datatype of the value passed in. All your parameters are created using Strings. Are you certain that all your database fields accepts strings?

Comment: also please post your table declaration

Comment: I suggest also to look at the InnerException inside that exception, Perhaps the situation will be more clear (if ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message)

Comment: @Banana, Ok I will try.

Comment: @Steve, most of those are strings, but I have BIGINT there which are the mobile no. & tel no.

Comment: i got the error "Parameter @second_batchWhere' must be defined". Ok' I'll try what could I possibly do to fix dis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your syntax there is an error. Between the last parameter and the WHERE clause a space is missing.

```
 "secondary_batch = @secondary_batch" & _
 " WHERE facultyNo = @facultyNo"
  ^
```

This is a simple typo but I would also suggest to avoid the use of AddWithValue.

AddWithValue decides the DataType of the parameter passed looking at the datatype of the value passed in. Because all your parameters are created using strings then all the fields of your table should be able to receive strings as value or someone between your code and the database should be able to convert from string to the expected datatype .

In this article ['Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?'](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) is explained why AddWithValue should be avoided (or at least used with extreme care).

For example, your field Age is probably a numeric datafield. So, instead of AddWithValue I would use

```
Dim age as Integer
if Int32.TryParse(txtAge.Text, age) = False Then
    // Error message and exit from the save
....

cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@age", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = age
```

In this way you could specify exactly the datatype of the parameter and you will pass a correct value to your datatable field

Comment: Wow, I never realised that before. So whitespacing sometimes matter. Anyway thanks a lot. And using Addwithvalue? Yes, Im so tired of that.

Answer (score 2):

This error is mostly caused by a missing or incorrectly spelled parameter declarations, eg. `@FirstName` mistakenly spelled as `@FirtName`.

Make sure that all the parameters that are declared in the SQL query are all declared in the AddwithValue Parameter declaration. (It helps to count the query versus the Addwithvalues).

The best solution is for Visual Studio to provide information about the missing parameter.  Use a Try-Catch block. In the catch block use `Messagebox.show(ex.Innerexception.Message)` instead of `Messagebox.show(ex.message)`. This will show the *exact* parameter that is missing, eg. below.

```
Try
      conCommand.Parameters.Addwithvalue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.text)
      conCommand.Parameters.Addwithvalue("@MiddleName", txtMiddleName.text)
      conCommand.Parameters.Addwithvalue("@LastName", txtLastName.text)
      conCommand.Parameters.Addwithvalue("@PhoneNo", txtPhoneno.text) 
catch ex as exception          
Messagebox.show(ex.innerexception.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: use `conCommand.prepare()` in try block. An exception just throw when calling prepare or execute functions not in addWithValue function.